# PyMongo save List of dict in subfield with own ObjectId for every dict entry

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm creating a list of Objects in my script, and want so save/update them in a subfield of an mongo db document.

My Objects looks like this:

```
class IndividualRating:
    def __init__(self, place=0, player="", team="", games="", legs=""):
        self.place = place
        self.player = player
        self.team = team
        self.games = games
        self.legs = legs
```

in my process i'm generating a list of this objects

```
ratings = []
for row in rows:
    rating = IndividualRating()
    # defining here the values
    ratings.append(rating.__dict__)
```

than later i want to save or update this in my mongodb

```
def save_ratings(league_id, season_id, ratings):
    database.individualratings.update_one(
    {
        "seasonId": season_id,
        "leagueId": league_id
    },
    {
        "$setOnInsert": {
            "seasonId": season_id,
            "leagueId": league_id
        },
        "$set": {
            "player": ratings
        }
    },
    upsert=True
    )
```

this code works in principle, but the objects under "player" are saved without an ObjectId. And i want an ObjectId for every Object under "player".

As Example

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('someLongId'),
    seasonId: 56267,
    leagueId: 27273,
    player: [
      {
          <- Here should be an ObjectId
          place: 1,
          player: "Some Player Name",
          team: "Some Team Name",
          games: "2:0",
          legs: "10:0"
      },
      {
          <- Here should be an ObjectId
          place: 2,
          player: "Some Player Name",
          team: "Some Team Name",
          games: "2:0",
          legs: "10:0"
      }
    ]
}
```

How to insert a list of objects (dict's) with ObjectIds in a subfield of a document?

Answer (score 0):

As your `IndividualRating` objects are not inserted as root documents, there is no reason, why your mongodb driver should generate an `ObjectId` for each of the array members. If you really need this unique identifier for your `IndividualRating` object, you need to generate the id yourself.

Add the following import:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

Add the following variable to your `IndividualRating` object:

```py
self._id = ObjectId()
```

For each object an unique ID will be generated.